# Negative Lookahead work around

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Hello fellow StackExchange users,

I am trying to create RegEx using something similar to Flex to block Angler EK payload websites on our proxies. The problem is that I am unable to use negative lookaheads. The only form of "negative" allowed is negated character sets ie: [^a-zA-Z0-9-/] and the like.

Peers of mine have created the following, but it includes negative lookaheads which leaves it near useless. Can anyone provide creative work arounds? I have included a sanitized example of the URLs we need to block.

```
^http:\/\/(?!www)[^\x2f]+\/(?![A-Z]{2,}\/|[A-Z][a-z]{2,}\/|[a-z]{3,}\/|TextHere\/)(?:[a-z0-9A-Z_\.-]+\/)*\?[a-z]=(?![0-9,\.]{6,}&|[0-9]{2,32}&)(?:[^\x3d]{2,32}=[^\x26]*&[a-z]=){2,}[^\x2f]{2,32}$
```

`meow://s4mpl3.s4mpl3.top/?l=&k=2OuX2&p=ESexoc&m=&i=cZzwP0gj_&j=kssjA2k&t=yNQx2&s=&a=HruxaXM0&e=ka5DwfIx`

Comment: What flavor of regex is this? Or what programming language is using this regex? If you can't use negative lookaheads, there are probably other limitations too.

Comment: Flex used on Cisco Ironports

Comment: If this is used in an `if` expression, can you use a positive lookahead and negate the result?

Comment: I looked it up, and the regex flavor is "POSIX ERE". It doesn't support any kind of `(?...)` syntaxes. I found the specifications on pages 290-291 of [this document](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/security/wsa/wsa6-3/user_guide/WSA_6-3-0_GA_UserGuide.pdf).

Comment: @4castle: well that pretty much prohibits a pure regex solution.

Comment: Can you give some more sample cases of urls that this should or shouldn't match? I'm have trouble figuring out what **would** match this regex. Or if it's easier, you could try to explain the goals of the regex in case it needs to be redesigned completely.

Comment: meow://sample.sample.top/?a=Ot_thS_&p=&s=FAED&c=uhbT&f=r9t&v=6gBxTs8&h=ielQ_gQt&k=qU56VkfTzZvrDn8
meow://sample.sample.com/?h=4WH8J&d=KBm&s=U4h-ivS8&p=mZ6SV87jk&w=p5ji&a=NS6M9xWG&v=bIyQQB6jRUd
meow://sample.sample.com/?f=&w=o4lyKV95&j=kSx7m&v=&m=8n0x&q=BZjLS&t=tn5Mp&x=Rvj3vyFpN&g=&l=OE8U868QIy&r=&y=8Y

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me a url that **is** matched by the current regex?

Comment: It's hard to say what the goal is, we have a list of 19 sample URLs we've gathered that are confirmed landing pages for Angler. Limiting the characters helps prevent false positives from long url's, but we're still seeing 1,000's of potential blocks from websites like CBS.com that have 1,000's of web pages with seemingly just as random of a structure after the TLD.

Comment: @4castle2 The regex in the question works with 0 false positives; however, the code is not compatible with Cisco Ironports proxies. I have written some regex with very, very little success. Examples from my train wreck of an attempt has resulted with a few of these FP's in order to help you prevent from reaching the same conclusion as myself.  http://www.artvan[.]com/Furniture/Store/ArtVanCategoryDisplayView?No=192&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&Nrp=96&storeId=10052&N=141+78      http://api-app.espn.com/v1/watch/listings?apikey=cefzdw27d5qrbv24ztzng53z&types=live&networks=espn1

Comment: Let me know if you'd like more to test with.   http://www.bing.com/th?id=A80d33adde4846caaef4cb90c4f30324b&w=80&h=80&qlt=90&p=0&pid=RS

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve this problem from the wrong perspective. Try to narrow down what URLs **are** allowed, instead of listing every URL format that *isn't* allowed. Once you've filtered out the URLs that are in the appropriate format, then run them through some more regexen that locate specific blacklisted character sequences (like `www` or your 19 confirmed malicious sites).

Since even you aren't sure what those safe URLs would be, I can't help with creating that regex until you figure out what you're trying to allow.

Comment: Implicit deny on a proxy seems like a bad idea. I appreciate the answer though!

Comment: I don't get your meaning. What's implicit about it?